# Read Comma Separated Value and Display in 2 Columns - Jquery

Tags: jquery

**I am using the following Jquery Script to display page contents displayImages.php**

```
 <div id="siteloader"></div>​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://www.abc.com/displayImages.php">');
    </script>
```

**Which works great and show filename as** `ball.jpg,lotus.jpg,ScanImage6640.jpg`

**What i am trying to do is** 
**(1) to get the results in a string 
(2) Split Comma separated value from above results and display the image in image tag as example**
`<img src="http://abc.com/images/ball.jpg">` `<img src="http://abc.com/images/lotus.jpg">`

3) **Then Add a** `<BR>` **after 2 columns and display the third and 4th image and soon...** 
so the result would be like below
[image]

Comment: And how would you get the data from the object you loaded? It seems cross domain to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your comma separated string available:

```
var str = 'ball.jpg,lotus.jpg,ScanImage6640.jpg',
    arr = str.split(',');

$.each(arr, function(k, v){

     //create an image element and append it somewhere
     var $imageElement = $('<img/>').prop({ src: v });

     $imageElement.appendTo('#something');

     if(k % 2 === 0) //each even iteration (0,2,4,6 etc)
                     //use i % 3 === 0 for each third row etc.
         $('#something').append('<br/>');
});
```

This should get you started. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: so would it be $("#siteloader").split ?

Comment: @user580950 Most likely `var arr = $("#siteloader").text().split(',');`

Comment: shall i add an image tag in html ?

Comment: @user580950 No, it's created dynamically. I've updated the code to make it more readable.

Comment: i uploaded the script here http://tinyurl.com/m6snqxf not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: @user580950 Paste it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @user580950 You need to wait for the object to be loaded. Also, you haven't modified any of the code at all. At least try to make it work

Comment: when i try do  alert(arr[0]); it doesnt display anything