# While user enters a value separated by comma in an input fields. The how to display the out put in list format

Tags: html

Here in this input fields. While user enters a value which is separated by a comma. For example like "apple,Banana,grapes,mango". So here if user enters the value in this format. Then I want to display the output in list format like

```
apple
Banana
grapes
mango
```

So if it can be done please let know how to do this. Below is my code where I have tried

```
<input type='text' id='idea' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

```
<script>
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    //First things first, we need our text:
    var text = document.getElementById("idea").value; //.value gets input values

    //Now construct a quick list element
    var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";

    //Now use appendChild and add it to the list!
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
</script>
```

Comment: with html only no, it is not possible. with javascript you can add this functionality while typing

Comment: please share if any resource that can follow that

Comment: you can do this using Javascript and Jquery, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184129/read-each-string-from-comma-separated-string-and-display-it-on-a-html-list-using/46184235) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894288/read-comma-separated-value-and-display-in-2-columns-jquery)

Comment: above I have updated the code where I am going wrong please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, but you can not append HTML in strings, you need to create proper list item objects and append those:

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  // cache the list
  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  
  //First things first, we need our text:
  const items = document.getElementById("idea").value.split(','); //.value gets input values, .split(',') makes it an array of values
  
  // foreach entry in the text array, create and append an li
  for (const item of items) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = item;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='idea' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
<ul id='list'></ul>
```